# Django-suit admin for loop in tab

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin, django-suit

I'm trying to create a tab with the django-suit extension to view a quote and list all the quote items. I'm not quite sure how to do this within the django-suit extension as I knwo nromally I would use the `{% for items in x %}` type templating code.

If anyone has any experience working with this extension and accomplishing this task, or if perhaps I can do it some other way, passing the primary key using `original.pk` that would be great.

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Quote(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateField('Date Issued')
    client = models.ForeignKey('organizations.Contact')
    gst = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='GST Applicable')
    assigned = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Quote Assigned')
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.date.__str__().replace("-", "") + "-" + self.id.__str__().zfill(3)


class QuoteItem(models.Model):
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField()  # For Suit order sorting
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Quote)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

view_quote.html

```
<h2 class="legend">View Invoice
</h2><br>
{% if original.pk %}
    <span>Invoice Information</span>
    <table class="table-overview">
        <tr>
            <th>Invoice ID</th>
            <td>
                {{ original }}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Description</th>
            <td>
                {{ original.description }}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Client</th>
            <td>
                {{ original.client }}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Notes</th>
            <td>
                {{ original.notes }}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <span>Invoice Items</span>
    <table class="table-overview">
        <tr>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>

        {% for items in original.quoteitems %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{ items.description }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ items.price }}
            </td>            <td>
                {{ items.quantity }}
            </td>            <td>
                {{ items.total }}
            </td>


        </tr>
    {%  endfor %}

    </table>
{% else %}
    Item is not saved yet
{% endif %}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had to change models.py with related_name

```
class QuoteItem(models.Model):
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField()  # For Suit order sorting
    quote = models.ForeignKey(Quote, related_name='quote_set') <<
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
```

and view_quote.html

```
{% for item in original.quote_set.all %}
<tr>
    <td>
        {{ item.description }}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{ item.price }}
    </td>            <td>
        {{ item.quantity }}
    </td>            <td>
        {{ item.total }}
    </td>


</tr>
{%  endfor %}
```